# Get VM Name and Details Filter By HTTP(80) Endpoint

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, endpoint

I have a few VM on the same Microsoft Azure Cloud service and I want to get only the Instances(VMs) name with the endpoint of HTTP(Port 80TCP) with Powershell commands.

This is right now my small code!
**Get-AzureVM -ServiceName | Get-AzureEndpoint | Where-Object {$_.Port -eq 80}**

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `Get-AzureEndpoint` you no longer have *VM* objects, you have *Endpoint* objects, which have different properties. You then filter out the endpoints you want, but now you are missing the properties of the VMs.

Possible solution: loop through all endpoints of each VM

```
$VMs = Get-AzureVM 'myservicename'
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    # check if the current VM has an endpoint with port 80
    $HttpEndpoint = Get-AzureEndpoint -VM $VM | where { $_.Port -eq 80 }
    if ($HttpEndpoint) {
        $VM.Name
    }
}
```

This is assuming, the endpoints don't contain the name of the VM they belong to. Otherwise you could of course just do

```
... where { $_.Port -eq 80 } | select InstanceName  # or whatever the name of the property with the VM name is
```

Followup:
To query additional ports:

```
where { $_.Port -eq 80 -or $_.Port -eq 443 }
```

or:

```
where { 80, 443 -contains $_.Port }
```

or with PowerShell 3 and later:

```
where { $_.Port -in 80, 443 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Swonkie I really appreciate your help. This really helps me :-) !!!